# How to avoid downloading Ivy dependencies in Docker?

Tags: docker, dependency-management, ivy, playframework-2.3

I have a Dockerfile that builds a Docker container to make my Play 2.3.x application running and easy to deploy.

The problem is that every time I want to test my container, it literally downloads *all the internet*.

Here is an extract of my file *(I removed some parts for clarity)* :

```
RUN git clone commons-library.git
RUN activator publish-local

RUN git clone my-app.git
CMD activator start
```

When I execute `docker build -t my-container .`, the `RUN activator publish-local` downloads everything every time.

I tried to mount my local `~/.ivy2` repository but mounting a volume does not work with Docker during `build` for portability reasons.

So how to do to avoid downloading every dependency each time the Docker container is built (at least for testing purposes) ?

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem and found http://blog.flurdy.com/2014/11/dont-download-internet-share-maven-ivy-docker.html it make sense and might help.

The idea is having a volume container having the dependencies on it and share it among all projects.